# /etc/resolv.conf file in pod with new search domain "com", how to make it work in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, dns

kubernets: v1.23

Recently, when I send a request to the api of auth0 in the pod, I encountered the problem of `x509 failed verified`. After some inspection, it was found that there was an extra com domain name in `/etc/resolv.conf`. When I removed it, everything worked fine. After digging deeper, I found that this file is determined according to the corresponding file of the k8s control node.
Currently I take measures to stop `networkmanager` from updating the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and avoid the problem.
But when I send the request directly in node, I have no problem. So `com` domain itself is no problem. Then how to configure it in k8s to make the `com` domain work?

Comment: x509 error deals with domain certificate related issues. x509 failed verified error states that ssl certificate which you are using for your domain is either broken or from an untrusted authority. sometimes it might even happen when the domain name you are using while generating the ssl certificate differs from the domain to which you have configured the ssl certificate, that includes subdomains. It would be helpful if you provide any steps or documents for replicating the error.